# Laravel FatalErrorException

Tags: laravel

I created a new view, route and controller in laravel and when i go to access the view i get an error, all other views are fine.

Error
FatalErrorException in shopsalescontroller.php line 11: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting ',' or ';'

this is my shop sales controller:

```
   <?php
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use App\Http\Requests;
   use App\shopsales

   class shopsalescontroller extends Controller : (line 11)
    {
     public function index()
      {
       $storeNum = request('storeNum');
       $results = shopsales::where('StoreNumber','=',$storeNum)->get();
       return view('shopSales',compact('results'));
      }
    }
```

PHP version 5.6.3
Zend engine v2.6.0

Laravel framework version 5.2.45

Comment: `use App\shopsales;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a semicolon on this line:

```
use App\shopsales;
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! Been staring at all my code for so long, was always going to be something silly!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the : (line 11) text from your code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

use App\shopsales

class shopsalescontroller extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        $storeNum = request('storeNum');
        $results = shopsales::where('StoreNumber', '=', $storeNum)->get();
        return view('shopSales', compact('results'));
    }

}
```

Comment: i put that there to indicate that was the line giving the error. Error still persists